# Install printer drives on multiple VDI's

Tags: printing, vdi

I need to install one printer driver on multiple VDI's so that the local printer will be redirected (if I don't install the printer drivers, it does not redirect properly). On one of the VDI's I have via a RDP session added a local printer, installed the drivers and afterwards removed the local printer. And that works fine and is all I need. Is there a way to do this without having to RDP and install a local printer?

Comment: What VDI technology? If you are using VMware View in linked-clone configuration with persistent desktops, you could update the base image and recompose the desktops...

Comment: you can avoid havin to do that by using a print server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Print Management MMC Console (In [RSAT](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d) if you don't have it already) to add the Print Driver to the Base Image.